# Importing SQLite integer column which is > 2^31-1

Tags: r, sqlite, rsqlite

I have a `table` in a SQLite database `DB` that I want to import in R. Yet one column `integer` of `table` is a SQLite integer datatype that might assume values > 2^31-1, then more than what supported by the R integer dataype. Yet RSQLite will proceed to import all the values from the column `integer` as integers into a R dataframe:

```
require(RSQLite)
con <- dbConnect("SQLite", dbname = DB)
query <- dbSendQuery(con, "SELECT * FROM table") 
result <- fetch(query, n = -1, encoding="utf-8")
dbClearResult(query)
dbDisconnect(con)
return(result)
```

Is there anyway to specify the datatype of the column of the target dataframe in R?